# How to filter out Mongodb _id value in clojure?

Tags: mongodb, clojure

When I retrieve Document from MongoDB, I want to filter out the id field in clojure?

For example,

```
({:name "maran",  :_id #<ObjectId 4e1d4afae8b2ef06ba2b7dd0>}
 {:name "abimaran", :_id #<ObjectId 4e1d4b12e8b2ef06ba2b7dd1>}
 {:name "hi",     :_id #<ObjectId 4e1d6d30e8b2ef06ba2b7dd2>}
 {:name "hello",  :_id #<ObjectId 4e1fbff7e1b419e1c75978e3>})
```

I need to filter out the _id field in the above map in clojure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(map #(dissoc % :_id) seq-you-get-from-mongo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [CongoMongo](https://github.com/aboekhoff/congomongo/blob/master/src/somnium/congomongo.clj) you can also filter keys you are retrieving from MongoDB:

```
(fetch :table :where {:foo "bar"} :only [:foo])
```